# hidden symbol `__sync_fetch_and_add_4' is referenced by DSO

Tags: gcc, g++

I am trying to Cross Compile opencv on linux platform (ARM 8148).
I am getting following errors:

```
warning: libQtTest.so.4, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libQtCore.so.4, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: ../../bin/opencv_perf_core: hidden symbol `__sync_fetch_and_add_4' in /opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/libgcc.a(linux-atomic.o) is referenced by DSO
/opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
```

I am not able to understand this error and on net also not getting proper reference for that .Can anyone help me in understanding this error .

Answer (score 1):

__sync_fetch_and_add_x* is normally inlined by gcc, and compiles to inline code that performs an automic operation on a memory word.

You will find them documented here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html

As described on this page, if the compiler emitted a function call, instead of a generating inline assembly, it means that this atomic operation is not supported on the target platform.